# Android Studio AVD is not launching

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I have installed the latest version of Android Studio on Windows 7 32-bit.

I have created a welcome app, but when I try to test it using AVD it's not launching, instead it's showing the error below:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug, :app:assembleDebugTest]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:compileDebugJava
:app:preDexDebug
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.

FAILED

The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    E:\Android\AndroidStudio\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --output E:\Android\AndroidStudio\WorkLocation\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-0f52de9bbc91bb9956813aaf2c6f0ff9d0160fa0.jar E:\Android\AndroidStudio\WorkLocation\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.2\classes.jar
Error Code:     1
Output: The system cannot find the path specified.    

Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
Total time: 24.154 secs

**Failed to complete Gradle execution
Cause:**
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).

Comment: It's not the AVD problem, it's about your gradle build process, clean your project and rebuild